# Resize image between textviews with layout file

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to have a layout which like this

```
       [text]
___________________
[                 ]
[     image       ]
[                 ]
[_________________]
      [text]
```

The image is too big for some screen sizes so I want the image to use the biggest size that still fits. Basically like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="@string/titel" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/bigimage" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="@string/subtitle" />
</LinearLayout>
```

But the image always pushes the subtitle text beyond the screen. I also tried a RelativLayout with the image in the center and text with layout_above and layout_below but that does not work either. I use the this layout in a fragment but that should not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going off the "layout" you have shown, this can be done with a `LinearLayout`, you just need to use `layout_weight`.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="@string/titel" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/bigimage" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="@string/subtitle" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This can also be done with a `RelativeLayout`, but the `TextView`s need to be the anchors, not the `ImageView`, that is why the image was pushing your text off the bottom of the screen.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="@string/titel" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/subtitle"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/bigimage" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="@string/subtitle" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I was sure that I try the first solution before. For the second solution. I think will put text at the bottom and top of the screen if the image is not big enough. I did not try it because the first solution already worked fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try to set for both `TextView` width `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`.